# Data binding with property editors when application context loads up

Tags: spring, data-binding, propertyeditor

I understand the principle of data binding of properties onto target with custom or default PropertyEditor. You specify a target bean and then bind properties onto it.

What I can't find out is how this binding works in bean definitions. What are the default PropertyEditors that are applied when you do something like this :

custom.property=a,b,c,d

```
<util:properties id="properties" location="classpath:my.properties" />
<bean class="com.example.SomeType">
    <property name="foo" value="${custom.property}" />
</bean>
```

And how would I add my custom editor to those applied when app context is being loaded up. In this case for converting  string a,b,c,d into string array, because foo is String[].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [right here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-beans-conversion-customeditor-registration) and [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-beans-conversion) in spring documentation.

See:

```
PropertyEditorRegistrySupport.createDefaultEditors();
```